# protobuffers - long value changes

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers, grpc

I have a c++ 32bit GRPC server.

And the client is a java 64bit GRPC application.

I am sending a message to the server that contains a long.

When the server receives the message the value has changed.

**The problem**

On the client I send 1512345600000.

On server I see 517111808.

Comment: The value has not changed, it seems you have read only first 4 bytes from your long instead of 8,  `517111808 -> 0x1ED2'8000`, `1512345600000 -> 0x160'1ED2'8000` do you see it ? You should put the code where you are reading the value, what data type are you using to hold this value ?

Comment: we need either a [mcve] or a magic crystal ball to know what is wrong with your code

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <cstdint>

using namespace std;

int64_t YourFunctionToRead()
{
   // don't use 'long' as type
   // it only guarantees to be at least 32bit, but certainly doesn't have to be 64bit
   // while you need 64bit type
   int64_t veryLongIntToRead = GRPCFunc();
   return veryLongIntToRead;
}
```

Also, you may have endianess problem. Isn't Java runtime big endian? C++ certainly doesn't assume little or big endian. GPRC most likely handles this for you. Just food for thought.